# Combining to elements for a focus function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I combine two elements to use the focus function? #s_type and #s_ctry I'm trying to avoid extra code by retyping the same exact thing twice.

the way i'm trying it now doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#s_type", "#s_ctry").focus(function() {
        var first = $(this).find("option").eq(0);
        if(first.val() === "0") {
            first.remove();
        }
    });
});    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a comma in the selector itself:

```
$("#s_type, #s_ctry")
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there! You need to combine them into one string. When you pass 2 arguments to jQuery, the second one is a context in which to match the selector, you can't provide multiple selectors as separate arguments:

```
$("#s_type, #s_ctry").focus(function() {
    //Do stuff!
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method to add elements to the matched set:

```
$("#s_type").add("#s_ctry").focus(function() {
    //Do stuff!
});
```